# Cómo mostrar el icono meteorológico

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy creando una aplicacion de tiempo usando la api OpenWeather. Intento mostrar el icono meteorologico correspondiente a la ciudad seleccionada y el estado meteorologico.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

html:

```
<div class="column">
                    <div class="media-content">
                        <div class="content">
                            <p>
                                <strong>
                                        <h1 class="has-text-inf o"> {{ ciutatActual.weather[0].icon }} </h1>
                                </strong>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

jsvascript:

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#eltemps',
data: {
    selectedCity: "",
    ciutatActual: null,
    ciutats: [
            "Barcelona",
            "Lleida",
            "Zaragoza",
            "Sevilla",
            "Madrid",
            "Paris",
            "Melbourne",
            "Moscow",
            "Pekin",
            "Marrakech"]
},
created: function () {
    this.selectedCity = this.ciutats[0]
},
watch: {
    selectedCity: function (){
        this.getWeather(this.selectedCity)
    }
},
methods: {
    getWeather(city) {
        const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + '&units=metric&lang=ca&appid=8660dddfbe5f16ee37dbd6883d8f07d5';
        fetch(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(function (item) {
                vm.ciutatActual = item;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    },
    itemClicked: function(item) {
        this.getWeather();
        this.onClick(item);
    }
}
```

})

El fallo viene de aqui:  {{ ciutatActual.weather[0].icon }}

que en vez de mostarr el icono me muestra solo un codigo

Answer (score 0):

es porque solo estas mostrando para que te muestre el código del icono, te falta la etiqueta `img` y la `url` de la imagen, quedaría algo así:

```
<h1 class="has-text-inf o"><img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{ciutatActual.weather[0].icon}}@2x.png"> </h1>
```

podes usar `@2` para traer un icono chico, o bien `@4` para traer un icono mediano.

espero que te pueda ayudar con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, suerte!

Comment: Gracias @Daniel por tu respuesta.

Comment: He probado la solución pero ahora me sale el icono de imagen vacio, sin contenido

Comment: Hola, perdon por la tardanza, me di cuenta que estas trabajando con Vue,js ahi cambian los parametros para la url de la img, integra esto: <img :src="`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${{ciutatActual.weather[0].icon}}@2x.png`"/>

Comment: Gracias @Daniel,
Lo he probado pero me sale lo mismo que antes, el icono de foto sin contenido